# Is it better to check a variable before setting its value in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, variables

If I have a boolean and some code which maybe changes it, and then I want to set it to `true`, should I check if it's `false`?

For example:

```
bool b = false;
// Some code
// Here "b" can be true or false
if (cond) {
    b = true;
}
```

vs

```
bool b = false;
// Some code
// Here `b` can be `true` or `false`
if (cond && !b){
    b = true;
}
```

Which is faster?

**Note**:

I ask that because of the following implementation of [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes): http://bloc.gerardfarras.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/erastotenes.txt

```
if (( i % divisor == 0 ) && ( numsprimers[i] == 0 )) {
    numsprimers[i] = 1;
}
```

(If `numsprimers[i]==1` it means that `i` isn't a prime number. And if it's 0 it can be prime or not)

Comment: Another way to think of it as: "Why check? Just overwrite!"

Comment: @Mysticial actually I remember a program gaining a huge speed increase by checking a boolean value and then overwriting it rather than just overwriting it. I don't have a benchmark but maybe one would be worth doing...

Comment: @SethCarnegie Was it a user-defined type?

Comment: @Mysticial nope, it was a boolean, in an inner loop.

Comment: @SethCarnegie That's interesting...

Comment: Compare the time spent checking, or not checking, the variable against the time you've spent worrying about it. If checking first is actually faster, then any decent optimizing compiler should take care of that for you. Write first for clarity.

Comment: @Mysticial I realise it's just me talking with no evidence though. Maybe I can reproduce it or something.

Comment: @SethCarnegie If you *are* able to reproduce it, make it an SO question about why that's the case. It would be interesting. :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie Definitely try to put that into a question. I always went with my gut feeling and some hand-waving when doing that kind of thing. Maybe performing the check enables some nifty compiler optimizations as equality and realtionships betweens values can be assumed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's being very very nitpicky, but generally speaking it's better to just change the value.

Checking and setting a value have roughly the same overhead anyway, so why would you want to have to do both in some cases?

Now if you're wondering if you should overwrite some  custom type (lets say a list of 100000 words) or if you should check to see if it needs to be overwritten first (let's say by simply checking a boolean value or a timestamp) then you should check first, because the cost of checking a boolean or timestamp is much less than writing so many words to memory.

This is of course all dependent on various things such as whether or not the memory you are editing is in cache, how expensive the "check" is, how often you need to overwrite the value versus how often it does not need to be overwritten, and of course the size of the memory.

Comment: Given your Sieve, since the only possible values are 0 and 1, I see no reason to check the value of numsprimers[i] before changing it.  This results in several instructions after all: Get value of nuprimers[i].  Compare it to 0.  Jump somewhere else in the code if it's 0.

Comment: long ago, maybe I still get an answer:
In my case the very most elements will still have the desired value = true.
So checking if value is still true could avoid setting it to true again.
Does "just changing the value without checking it before" still be an equal fast operation if we talk about tens of millions of elements in sum?

Comment: I find it odd that no-one here addresses multithreading. As far as I am aware (regardless of locking) writing makes a cache line "dirty" and forces all other cores to reload it, whereas reading doesn't. One obvious question that comes to mind is whether writing the same value to the cache marks it as dirty and forces a reload of other core caches, which, under certain circumstances, would definitely make the "just overwrite" option slower than the check and overwrite (as the check would leave the cache of other cores intact).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if ( b = !!cond ) {

}
```

Where you check the condition and apply the value to `b`, if it is necessary for `b` to have a value. If you want `b` to stay true then I say to use one of your other examples. It shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: But maybe `cond` is `false` and `b` is `true`. I want `b` to remain `true`.